# MySQLInterfaceError when committing the change to database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am developing an API client that pulls back data from various sources and push them into a MySQL database using SQLAlchemy. I keep getting error messages like this every time I try to commit the change I made to the table:

```
MySQLInterfaceError:Python type list cannot be converted
```

The data model I am using is like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Image(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Images"

    url = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    fileName = Column(String)
    parameterKey = Column(String)
    phase = Column(String)
    xmlFileName = Column(String)
    dateModified = Column(DateTime)
```

The code I using to insert the object to the table is:

```
 Session = sessionmaker(engine)
    for data in dataset:
        with Session.begin() as session:
            try:
                record = Image(**data)
                session.add(record)
                session.commit()

            except SQLAlchemyError as err:
                error = str(err.__dict__)
                print(error)

            finally:
                session.close()
```

I don't understand why it keeps giving me error messages involves `list`. Has anyone encountered similar issues? If so, can you please help me resolve this problem? Thanks!

`Update`: I ran it using Jupyter, and the full error message is:

````
'orig': ProgrammingError(-1, "Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type", None), 'ismulti': False, 'hide_parameters': False, 'detail': [], 'connection_invalidated': False}```
````

Comment: What is `type(data)` ?

Comment: It's ```dict```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the data I pull back contains an `list` object, all I need to do is changing `[]` to a `string`.